# mapping custom dictionary to tweet dataframe

Tags: dictionary, mapping, nltk, lexicon

I build my custom dictionary and now i want to map it to my tweet dataframe. How can i do that?

so basically, I have this 3 dictionary. Positive, negative and neutral words. I have twitter dataset and I want to map my dictionary to that dataset to determine the sentiment of each tweet. This is what I have done so far.

```
positive='1'
negative='-1'
neutral ='0'

pos_Words=set(['good','beautiful','best',])
neg_Words=set(['bad','suck','damn'])

def sentiment(words):
    pslen= len(pos_Words.intersection(words))
    nglen= len(neg_Words.intersection(words))

    if pslen > nglen:
        return positive
    elif pslen < nglen:
        return negative
    else:
        return neutral

from collections import Counter

def count_senti(sentences):
    sents = Counter()
    words = Counter()

    for sentence in sentences:
        senti = sentiment(sentence)
        sents[senti] += 1
        words[senti]+= len(sentence)
    return sents,words

import nltk
def parse_senti(text):

    sentences = [
        [word.lower() for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)]
        for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    ]

    sents, words = count_senti(sentences)
    total = sum(words.values())

    for sentiment, count in words.items():
        pcent = (count / total) * 100
        nsents = sents[sentiment]

        print(
            pcent,sentiment,nsents
        )

parse_senti('good. bad')
```

the result is 
66.66666666666666 1 1
33.33333333333333 -1 1

but i want it to map to each tweet in my twitter dataframe which written in csv.

and idea please?

i did
parse_senti('dataframe')

error occur 
expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

how silly am i, solve it.

just iterate the function for every row in my data frame then it will solve the issue.

```
df['sentiment'] = df[0].apply(parse_senti)


   0          sentiment

0   bad     (100.0, -1, 1)
1   good    (100.0, 1, 1)
```